# Refactored chained elsif (with regex) to dispatch table in Perl. But how my code works?

Tags: regex, perl

I had a long chained if elsif block like this where I capture output of the command using Capture::Tiny and then extract it using a series of regular expressions.

```
sub capture_cpu_test {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    print '--------------------', "\n";
    print 'COMMAND is: ', "$cmd", "\n";

    #capture an output of sysbench command
    my ( $stdout_to_format, $stderr, $exit ) = capture {
        system($cmd );
    };

    #split on newline to separately analyze later
    my @output_lines = split( "\n", $stdout_to_format );

    #set hash to collect param => param_value pairs
    my %plotting_hash = ();

    foreach my $line (@output_lines) {
        if ( $line =~ m/\ANumber\s+of\s+threads:\s+(\d+)\z/xms ) {
            $plotting_hash{num_threads}   = $1;
        }

        #long list of elseif continues

        elsif ( $line =~ m{\A\s+events\s+\(avg\/stddev\):\s+(.+?)\/(.+?)\z}xms ) {
            $plotting_hash{events_avg}    = $1;
            $plotting_hash{events_stddev} = $2;
        }
    }

    #returns ref to plotting_hash to combine upstream
    my $hash_plot_ref = \%plotting_hash;
    print 'Printing $hash_plot_ref inside capture_cpu_test: ', "\n";
    print Dumper($hash_plot_ref);
    return $hash_plot_ref;
}
```

I wanted to make it more readable so I changed this elsif block to dispatch table using the answers on the net and no problem, it works:

```
#set dispatch table with regex => sub {} pairs
my %plotting_hash  = ();
my %dispatch_regex = (
    qr/\ANumber\s+of\s+threads:\s+(\d+)\z/xms => 
      sub { $plotting_hash{num_threads}   = $1 },

    #more entries here

    qr{\A\s+events\s+\(avg\/stddev\):\s+(.+?)\/(.+?)\z}xms =>
      sub { $plotting_hash{events_avg}    = $1;
            $plotting_hash{events_stddev} = $2; },
);

#populate the %plotting_hash by calling dispatch table (%dispatch_regex)
my $code_ref;
foreach my $line (@output_lines) {
    foreach my $regex ( keys %dispatch_regex ) {
        if ( $line =~ $regex ) {
            $code_ref = $dispatch_regex{$regex};
            $code_ref->();
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

I get something like this:

```
$hash_plot_ref = {
      'num_threads'         => '4',
      'events_stddev'       => '50.98',
      'events_avg'          => '2500.0000',
      ...
};
```

1. I would like to know how this dispatch from regular expression on line of data to anonymous subroutine works. How captures ($1, $2) get transferred to anon sub? How exactly this anon subs get parameters? I tried to figure it out with B::Deparse but it does not tell much.
2. How could I write it more readable? I tried with tabulated ternaries and for/when (not shown here) and it still doesn't look much better than chained elseif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I would like to know how this dispatch from regular expression on line of data to anonymous subroutine works. How captures ($1, $2) get
>      transferred to anon sub? How exactly this anon subs get parameters? I
>      tried to figure it out with B::Deparse but it does not tell much.

$1 and $2 are like global variables. They are available everywhere. When the following line of code is executed:

```
if ( $line =~ $regex ) {
```

and if it succeeds, $1 and $2 etc will have the values from that successful match. By the way, you are aware that the

```
(something)
```

bits are used by the regex engine to supply $1, $2 etc?

> 2. How could I write it more readable? I tried with tabulated ternaries and for/when (not shown here) and it still doesn't look much
>      better than chained elseif.

Actually, once you understand what's going on, it's not too bad. To me I see a pattern and an associated block. I like that. The various parts are closer together and can be seen more easily than if they are spread out over more lines. Give yourself some time to understand and soon it will start to look meaningful.

I'm not sure what you mean about ternaries without spending some time *thinking*, - do you really want clarification? If so, post a new question, or ADD more information to this one so it can be addressed.

Comment: 1. Thank you for your clarification. Using global $1 and $2, ... seems unsafe. Do you know a way to make it more safe and keep the dispatch table working?
2. No clarification needed, it is just big block of code and that is fine for the problem at hand.